# Problem with accessing an atributes of an object i got from backend

Tags: javascript

Problem is in this code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Card, CardActions, CardContent, CardMedia, Button, Typography, ButtonBase } from '@material-ui/core/';
import DeleteIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Delete';
import MoreHorizIcon from '@material-ui/icons/MoreHoriz';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

import { deleteBook } from '../../../../actions/books';
import useStyles from "./styles";

const Book = (book, setCurrentId) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const classes = useStyles();
  const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('profile'));
  const history = useHistory();

  console.log(book);

  const openBook = (e) => {
    history.push(`/books/${book._id}`);
  };

  return (
    <Card className={classes.card} raised elevation={6}>
      <ButtonBase
        component="span"
        name="test"
        className={classes.cardAction}
        onClick={openBook}
      >
        <CardMedia className={classes.media} image={book.slika || 'https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/194400/49531010-48dad180-f8b1-11e8-8d89-1e61320e1d82.png'} title={book.ime_knjige} />
        {(user!= null && user.result.admin_stranice === true) && (
        <div className={classes.overlay2} name="edit">
          <Button
            onClick={(e) => {
              e.stopPropagation();
              setCurrentId(book._id);
            }}
            style={{ color: 'white' }}
            size="small"
          >
            <MoreHorizIcon fontSize="default" />
          </Button>
        </div>
        )}
        <Typography className={classes.title} gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">{book.ime_knjige}</Typography>
        <Typography className={classes.title} gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">{book.autor_knjige}</Typography>
        <CardContent>
          <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p">{book.opis_knjige && book.opis_knjige.split(' ').splice(0, 20).join(' ')}...</Typography>
          <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p> {book.rejting}</Typography>
        </CardContent>
        <div className={classes.details}>
          <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="h2 {book.zanr && book.zanr.map((zanr) => `#${zanr} `)}</Typography>
        </div>
      </ButtonBase>
      <CardActions className={classes.cardActions}>
        {(user && user.result.admin_stranice === true) && (
          <Button size="small" color="secondary" onClick={() => dispatch(deleteBook(book._id))}>
            <DeleteIcon fontSize="small" /> &nbsp; Delete
          </Button>
        )}
      </CardActions>
    </Card>
  );
};
export default Book;
```

The object "book" i pass here is defined and have all the atributes needed and their values. I used console.log to see object in console and it's there, with everything it should have. But when i try to access any of atributes the JavaScript sees them as undefined for some reason. Some idea why it does that?

Comment: Can't you just `console.log` the books to see at which state it still looks fine and at which state it is undefined? Then you would know that the error is somewhere inbetween

Comment: Are you using "mongoose"? If so, try `Book.find({}).sort({ _id: -1 }).limit(LIMIT).skip(startIndex).exec()` (with an empty object in "find" and add ".exec()" to the end) to get all books in database. Reference: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find

Comment: Add `.lean()`. `const books = await Book.find().sort({ _id: -1 }).limit(LIMIT).skip(startIndex).lean().exec();` This way you'll get pure and simple JSON, instead of heavy and complex Mongoose objects. And it's waaaay faster.

Comment: Nothing of these you recommended works. Actually all of the states are undefind. Nothing shows up.

Comment: @FilipNikolic At which state is it undefined? Already at `const books = await Book.find().sort({ _id: -1 }).limit(LIMIT).skip(startIndex);` or later? If it's already there you can remove the code that comes afterwards (make a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)). If it's later figure out where it becomes undefined